# Regex (Python) - Removing a line starting with a delimiter and keeping other delimiters

Tags: python, regex, split, delimiter

How do I separate something like this:

```
; Remove this line  
     (?A or :B
        (G + D))
```

Removing the lines with ; and separating tokens by spaces (removing spaces) and '(' or ')' as delimiters but keeping them using regex in python.

The end result should be something like:

```
['(', '?A', 'or', ':B', '(', 'G', '+', 'D', ')', ')']
```

But I can't eliminate the ';' line nor separate the '(', ')' tokens as their own.

So far I have this:

```
re.split('[;.*]*[^()\[\]:?a-zA-Z0-9-]+', text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
import re
rx = r'^;.*|([()])|\s+'
s = """; Remove this line  
     (?A or :B
        (G + D))"""
print(list(filter(None, re.split(rx, s, flags=re.M))))
# => ['(', '?A', 'or', ':B', '(', 'G', '+', 'D', ')', ')']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/le1i3i)

**Details**

- `^;.*` - start of a line (`flags=re.M` will make `^` match start of lines, too) and then `;` and any 0 or more chars other than line break chars
- `|` - or
- `([()])` - Capturing group 1 (once captured, the matches will be output within the resulting list): a `(` or `)` char
- `|` - or
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces (not captured, hence, these matches will be  left out).

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you very much. I just change the start of line since sometimes it could start with an empty space/tab, r'\s+;.*|([()])|\s+'